# How to Set Active Tab in jQuery Ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Can you please let me know how I can set the active tab in jquery ui with a button click out of the tabs?

I have a button like:

```
<input id="action" type="submit" value="Go to Action">
```

and here is the code,

```
<script>
$(function() {
 $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
 $( "#action" ).on("click", function(){});
});
```

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Description</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Resources</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>

<div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Description content</p>
</div>

<div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Action content</p>
</div>

<div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Resources content</p>
</div>

<div id="tabs-4">
    <p>Settings </p>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Inside  your function for the click action use

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ active: # });
```

Where # is replaced by the tab index you want to select.

Edit: change from selected to active, selected is deprecated

Comment: `selected` is deprecated since jQuery 1.9 and was removed from jQuery 1.10, it was replaced by `active`:
http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-selected-option-renamed-to-active

Comment: Just to add, the index is zero-based

Comment: i use this method but it show error that tab is not a funcation

Comment: For those getting the error `tab is not a function`, you need to include `jquery-ui`.

Answer (score 32):

Simple jQuery solution - find the `<a>` element where `href="x"` and click it:

```
$('a[href="#tabs-2"]').click();
```

Comment: FYI, this may have undesired side effects, as the event attached to the click may run asynchronously to your code, creating potential race conditions.

Answer (score 21):

Just to clarify in complete detail. This is what works with the current version of jQuery Ui

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active", # );
```

where # is the index of the tab you want to make active.

Answer (score 13):

Inside your function for the click action use

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ active: # });
```

Where `#` is replaced by the tab index you want to select.

Comment: This answer may seem like a duplicate of the top-voted accepted answer above, but that answer was actually edited after to duplicate this one

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Not quite George. If you look at my edit all I changed was selected -> active, the wording of this answer was copy and pasted from my original answer

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old question. But I think the way to change the selected tab have changed slight

The way to change the active tab now is by giving active the index of the tab. Note the index starts at 0 not 1. To make the **second** tab active you will use the the index 1.

```
//this will select your first tab
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ active: 0 });
```

Comment: In Firefox 84.0 [Jan 2021] the use of private fields (`#`, e.g. `#this_tab`) throws a "*Uncaught SyntaxError: private fields are not currently supporte*d" comment in the Developer Tools console, and the link opens in a new (Firefox, not JQuery) tab.  Specifying the tab *number* (per this answer) resolves this issue. For me, the other answers did not work.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to set the active tab by ID instead of index, you can also use the following:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({ active: $('#tabs ul').index($('#tab-101')) });
```

Comment: I liked your approach, and i'm using it, but the DOM indication (jQuery.index usage) is wrong, it should be as in the following:
$('#tabs>ul:first>li').index( $('a[href="'+window.location.hash+'"]').closest('li') );

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $('#action').click(function() {
        var selected = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");
        $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
    });
});
```

Also consider changing the input type as `button` instead of `submit` unless you want to submit the page.

Answer (score 3):

HTML: First you have o save the post tab index

```
<input type="hidden" name="hddIndiceTab" id="hddIndiceTab" value="<?php echo filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'hddIndiceTab');?>"/>
```

JS

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    active: $('#hddIndiceTab').val(), // activate the last tab selected
    activate: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#hddIndiceTab').val($( "#tabs" ).tabs( "option", "active" )); // save the tab index in the input hidden element
    }
});
```

Comment: I like this solution because it extends the jQuery UI framework to provide a helper.  However, it needs a way to provide a Text Label as input to make this very simple to be called from anywhere (not just event handlers).

Answer (score 2):

just trigger a click, it's work for me:

```
$("#tabX").trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to post this one-liner as a solution, as in the reply posted to Carl's approach:

```
$('#tabs>ul:first>li').index( $('a[href="'+window.location.hash+'"]').closest('li') );
```

Greetings

Answer (score -3):

If you want to active tab 2 from tab 1, do the following

```
$($("#tabs").find("li")[0])[0].className = "nav-item";  // tab 1
$($("#tabs").find("li")[1])[0].className = "nav-item active";  // tab 2

var aTab = $('#tabs-2'); // tab 2 content div

aTab[0].className = "tab-pane active";
```