# Set the Jquery tab as active if a parameter is set

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tabs

In my project, I am using jQuery tabs like,

```
<div class="video_b_tab" id="tabs">
  <ul class="video_b_tabul">
    <li class="video_b_tabli"><a href="#tabs-1" onclick="profilesetting('<?php echo base_url();?>')"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><span class="chngpspan"><?php echo lang('profile').' '.lang('settings')?></span></a></li>
    <li class="video_b_tabli"><a href="#tabs-2"  onclick="moviesetting('<?php echo $id;?>','<?php echo base_url();?>')"><i class="fa fa-film"></i><span class="chngpspan"><?php echo lang('movieset');?></span></a></li>
    <li class="video_b_tabli"><a href="#tabs-3"  onclick="usersetting('<?php echo $id;?>','<?php echo base_url();?>')"><i class="fa fa-film"></i><span class="chngpspan"><?php echo "User Settings";?></span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="v_dissc_tab" id="tabs-1">
        <div class="rightsettingdiv" id="profilediv"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="" id="tabs-2">
     <div class="moviesettings" id="moviediv"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="" id="tabs-3">
      <div class="moviesettings" id="usersetdiv"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mainsettingdiv"></div>
</div>
```

If the url contains the parameter `msg`, then I want to set `tabs-3` as selected.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
    if(window.location.search)
    {
        $("#tabs").tabs();   // want to set tab-3 as selected or active
    }
});
```

If a tab is active, the html will look like:

```
<li class="video_b_tabli ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tabs-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="true">
<a href="#tabs-2" onclick="moviesetting('1','http://neos.or/project/')" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2">
<i class="fa fa-film"></i>
<span class="chngpspan">Movie Settings</span>
</a>
</li>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: A guess you will find some solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21860793/5480737

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [active option](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.search) {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            active: 2 //0 based index
        }); // want to set tab-3 as selected or active
    }
});
```

If you want to change the active tab after creation of the tab widget you can use the [option method](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#method-option) like

```
$("#tabs").tabs('option', 'active', 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p3sfy/4256/)**

Try the following snippet :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       var url = window.location.href;

        var tab = url.indexOf('msg') >-1 ? 2 :0;    //tabs start from 0

        $("#tabs").tabs({
            active: tab
        }); 

        //or $("#tabs").tabs( "option", "active", tab );

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
    if(window.location.herf.indexOf('msg') > -1)
    {
        $("#tabs ul li:eq(2) a").click();   // want to set tab-3 as selected or active
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For selecting tab-3 via code, you can use:

```
$('#tabs').tabs('select','tabs-3')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking help from JS, use PHP shorthand if-else

```
<?php 
$tab = explode('#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>

In HTML
<li class="video_b_tabli" class="<?php echo ($tab[1] == "tabs-1") ? "active": null ?>" ><a href="#tabs-1"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><span class="chngpspan"><?php echo lang('profile').' '.lang('settings')?></span></a></li>
```