# Linking to a specific HTML tab of another page within the website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my home page there are 7 links. code of one link is given below.

```
<a id="mosquito-btn" href="~/general-pest-control.cshtml#nav-mosquito" class="btn btn-p btn-arrow">Read More</a>
```

On another page I have 7 tabs for each of the 7 links in the home page. when home page links are clicked I want to be redirected to the other page and open the specific tab.

```
    <nav>
       <div class="nav nav-tabs tabs-pest" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
       <a name="top"></a>
       <a class="tab-pest active" id="nav-mosquito-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-mosquito" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-mosquito" aria-selected="true"><img src="~/Images/tab-mosquito.png" /><span>Mosquito</span></a>
       </div>
   </nav>

   <div class="tab-content py-3 px-3 px-sm-0" id="nav-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-mosquito" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-mosquito-tab">
          <div class="row">
              <p>text></p>
          </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

At the moment only the first tab is opened on click of home page link.  How do I open tabs ?

Do I need jquery?

I tried with this one.
But it didn't work

```
var tabName = (window.location.href.match(/[?&]tab-name=[^&$]+/i) || '=').split('=')[1];

if (tabName.length)
    $('#nav-tabContent .tab-pest[href="~/general-pest-control.cshtml' + tabName + '"]').tab('show');
```

Comment: You mean you want to open a browser tab or html tabs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Set Active Tab in jQuery Ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860658/how-to-set-active-tab-in-jquery-ui)

Comment: @MahmoudMostafa Not a browser tab. A tab pane inside a website.

Answer (score 0):

Try with ***localStorage***:

Save id of clicked link in localstorage:

```
<a id="nav-mosquito-tab">

$("body").on("click","a",function(){
    localStorage.setItem("clickedTab",$(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Give the same id as before in page that contains tabs. And do click on the tab using `.click()`

```
<a class="tab-pest active" id="nav-mosquito-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-mosquito" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-mosquito" aria-selected="true"><img src="~/Images/tab-mosquito.png" /><span>Mosquito</span></a>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tab = localStorage.getItem("clickedTab");
    $("#"+tab).click();
});
```

Comment: Where do I write this ? <a id="nav-mosquito-tab">

Comment: You should write same id on both pages

Comment: I used the same id and added your jquery code in footer section where all <script> are there. BUT STILL NOT WORKING. Should I change something in the jquery code?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add an attribute `target="_blank"` in the anchor tag as shown below:

```html
<a href = "https://www.google.co.in" target="_blank">I will open this link in new tab</a>
```

I dont know why it isn't executable here. But [here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5svyjqt6/) link for the same.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) is a reference link for the same.

Comment: No What I want to open is HTML tabs inside the website. not browser tabs

Comment: @deeva, your question was unclear. Let me update my answer here.